# ASP.NET 3.5 C# custom error pages in webforms application

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, error-handling

I'm working on a personal website and I'm using webforms and .NET 3.5 and C#. I'm trying to get the custom error pages sorted but I can't get them to work properly. Not on my local IIS 7.5 as on the external server. It keeps prompting me with default IIS error pages when pages can't be found. How can it be fixed?

I've got the following section in my `web.config` file defining the errorpages;

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/ERRORPAGES/Default.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
    <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/ERRORPAGES/Default.aspx" />
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ERRORPAGES/404.aspx" />
     <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/ERRORPAGES/400.aspx" />
     <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ERRORPAGES/500.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

Comment: The 404 error is the only one not working? Are you browsing your remote site from outside the remote server?

Comment: None of them are working. Yes i'm browsing outside remote server. I upload the web.config file through FTP and then test by using it's domainname

Comment: If you set mode="Off" it's the same?

Comment: @Claudio tried it, changing the mode to On or Off doesn't matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out there was a problem with the server i was running. The host changed it and now online everything works as i expected it to be.